# Sort by date and get the latest value in CouchDB view

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I have documents with an id and timestamp which are not distinct.
For example I have something like below

| Id | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2021-02-22T09:11:21.961Z |
| b | 2021-02-22T09:11:21.961Z |
| c | 2021-02-22T09:11:21.961Z |
| a | 2021-02-22T19:21:11.861Z |
| c | 2021-02-22T19:21:11.861Z |

When I query the view with start and end keys I want the result to be just the recent values, such as

| Id | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2021-02-22T19:21:11.861Z |
| c | 2021-02-22T19:21:11.861Z |

I tried the following view/map function

```
function (doc) { 
 DeltaTime = new Date(doc.resultTime);
 DeltaTime.setMilliseconds(DeltaTime.getMilliseconds()-doc.Timestamp);
 FinalDate= new Date(DeltaTime);
 doc.al.forEach(e => 
 emit([new Date(FinalDate.setMilliseconds(FinalDate.getMilliseconds()+e.blk)),e.id16,e.pos.x,e.pos.y], // key
  {e.id16,e.pos.x,e.pos.y}) // value
)
 doc.tl.forEach(e => 
 emit([new Date(FinalDate.setMilliseconds(FinalDate.getMilliseconds()+e.t)),e.id16,e.pos.x,e.pos.y], // key
  {e.id16,e.pos.x,e.pos.y}) // value
)
}
```

with `_design/GetDeatails/_view/AnchorandTag?startkey=[%222021-02-22T09:11:21.961Z%22]&endkey=[%222021-02-24T11:11:22.061Z%22,{}]&descending=true`

It does not seem to be working. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please do not link to external images. Over time they may break and more importantly are a barrier for those with visual impairments.

Answer (score 0):

"It does not seem to be working" is a slippery comment.

`startkey=["2021-02-22T09:11:21.961Z"]&endkey=[%222021-02-24T11:11:22.061Z%22,{}]&descending=true`

*should* be returning an empty result. Why?

The related [CouchDB documentation](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#sorting-order-and-startkey-endkey) has the answer regarding the `descending` parameter when `descending=true` which relates to your issue - you are not swapping the start and end keys:

> ...results will be empty because the entries in the view are reversed
> before the key filter is applied, and therefore the endkey ...
> will be seen **before** the startkey ... resulting in an empty
> list.
>
> Instead, you should **reverse the values** supplied to the startkey and
> endkey parameters to match the descending sorting applied to the keys

(emphasis mine)

So when `descending=true` the query *must* swap the start and key values.

Below is a demo of this using pouchDB.  Note pouchDB returns a nice error message when the parameters are not swapped correctly.

I chose to keep it simple with this map function

```
function (doc) {             
  emit(doc.Timestamp,doc.Id);
}
```

so as to focus on the *actual problem* rather than replicating your complex key arrangement which, for this answer, just gets in the way.

```js
async function showViewDocs(title, elId, view, params) {
  // show title
  gel(elId).innerHTML = title;
  // show parameters
  gel(elId + "_params").innerText = "Parameters\n" + JSON.stringify(params, undefined, 2);
  //show result 
  let text;
  try {
    const result = await db.query(view, params);
    text = result.rows.map(row => [row.value, row.key].join('\t')).join('\n');
  } catch (err) {
    text = JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
  }
  gel(elId + "_result").innerText = "\nResults:\n---------------------------------\n" + text;
}

function getDocsToInstall() {
  const docs = [{
      "Id": "a",
      "Timestamp": "2021-02-22T09:11:21.961Z",
    },
    {
      "Id": "b",
      "Timestamp": "2021-02-22T09:11:21.961Z",
    },
    {
      "Id": "c",
      "Timestamp": "2021-02-22T09:11:21.961Z",
    },
    {
      "Id": "a",
      "Timestamp": "2021-02-22T19:21:11.861Z",
    },
    {
      "Id": "c",
      "Timestamp": "2021-02-22T19:21:11.861Z",
    }
  ];
  // design document
  const ddoc = {
    "_id": "_design/SO-67215994",
    "views": {
      "timestamp_id": {
        "map": `function (doc) {             
           emit(doc.Timestamp,doc.Id)
        }`
      }
    }
  };


  docs.push(ddoc);
  return docs;
}

const db = new PouchDB('SO-67215994', {
  adapter: 'memory'
});
// install docs and show view in various forms.
(async() => {
  const viewName = 'SO-67215994/timestamp_id';
  await db.bulkDocs(getDocsToInstall());

  //  show to raw view
  let params = {
    include_docs: false,
    reduce: false
  }
  await showViewDocs("Raw view", 'view', viewName, params);

  // descending = true; NOT swapping start/end keys (problem)
  params = {
    include_docs: false,
    reduce: false,
    descending: true,
    startkey: "2021-02-22T00:00:00.000Z",
    endkey: "2021-02-22T11:59:59.999Z"
  }
  await showViewDocs("Problem: Descending = true, start/end keys <em>NOT</em> swapped", 'date_range_1', viewName, params);
  //
  // descending = true; swap start/end keys.
  //
  params = {
    include_docs: false,
    reduce: false,
    descending: true, // <-- Descending, swap start/end keys.
    startkey: "2021-02-22T11:59:59.999Z",
    endkey: "2021-02-22T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
  await showViewDocs("Descending: start/end keys swapped", 'date_range_2', viewName, params);
})();

const gel = id => document.getElementById(id);
```

```css
.title {
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: .33em;
  color: black;
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pouchdb@7.1.1/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/download/7.1.1/pouchdb.memory.min.js"></script>
<div id="view" class="title"></div>
<pre id="view_params"></pre>
<pre id='view_result'></pre>
<div id="date_range_1" class="title"></div>
<pre id="date_range_1_params"></pre>
<pre id='date_range_1_result'></pre>
<div id="date_range_2" class="title"></div>
<pre id="date_range_2_params"></pre>
<pre id='date_range_2_result'></pre>
```